# Strange noise are comming from the speakers when I play audio

Tags: 16.04, sound, laptop

the sound was working fine until yesterday, I've tried a full test scan of my computer with the checkbox app then I canceled it and shut down the laptop.
Now I'm having strange loud noise coming from the speakers/headset whenever I play audio.

Please Help.

Answer (score 0):

### Lazy resolutions

If you consider that there might be a software issue you might be safe to reinstall the audio driver.
As a reference on how to do it you might be safe to follow [How to reinstall audio driver?](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1121805)

Quote [#3](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1121805&p=7049519#post7049519)

> The best thing to do would be to remove alsa and reinstall it. The same thing happened to me when I switched mobos and this fixed it.
>
> (1) Remove the ALSA packages
>
> sudo apt-get --purge remove linux-sound-base alsa-base alsa-utils
>
> (2) Reinstall the same packages
>
> sudo apt-get install linux-sound-base alsa-base alsa-utils
>
> Packages gdm and ubuntu-desktop are also removed in this process if
>   you are using Gnome. They need to be reinstalled:
>
> sudo apt-get install gdm ubuntu-desktop
>
> If you are using xubuntu this will also happen to you
>
> sudo apt-get install gdm xubuntu-desktop
>
> (3) Reboot.

### Right direction

While this might not be the answer you are looking for be sure the cables and internal wires are all connected properly and try different headphones. As a test you can run in console :

```
sound-test -c2 -t wav
```

#### From the man page of sound-test:

```
SPEAKER-TEST(1)                                General Commands Manual                                SPEAKER-TEST(1)

NAME
       speaker-test - command-line speaker test tone generator for ALSA

SYNOPSIS
       speaker-test [-options]

DESCRIPTION
       speaker-test generates a tone that can be used to test the speakers of a computer.

       speaker-test  by  default will test the default device. If you want to test another sound device you will have
       first to get a list of all of the sound cards in your system and the  devices  associated  with  those  cards.
       Notice  that  there  might be for example, one device for analog sound, one for digital sound and one for HDMI
       sound.  To get the list of available cards and devices you can run aplay -L.
```

So each command means 
-c2:

```
-c | --channels NUM
              NUM channels in stream
```

-t wav:

```
-t | --test pink|sine|wav
              -t pink means use pink noise (default).

              Pink noise is perceptually uniform noise -- that is, it sounds like every frequency at  once.   If  you
              can hear any tone it may indicate resonances in your speaker system or room.

              -t sine means to use sine wave.

              -t wav means to play WAV files, either pre-defined files or given via -w option.

              You can pass the number from 1 to 3 as a backward compatibility.
```

More information on how regarding the sound troubleshooting you can find at

[Troubleshooting Linux Sound | troubleshooters](http://www.troubleshooters.com/linux/sound/sound_troubleshooting.htm)

Comment: Thank you for helping but this didn't solve the issue :(